# Shader works just fine in Unity Editor, but became black in WebGL build

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, unity-webgl

I am working on a project which encodes sensor values at different positions into a 3d heatmap of a building. I use a vertex shader for this purpose and this works just fine in Editor:[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ge6s.png), but after I built the scene in WebGL, this turned out to be [black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyQkb.png).

I has tried using constant loop indices or always include this shader in project settings etc., but none of these works. Here are some of the code:

```
                v2f vert(appdata v)
                {
                    v2f o;
                    o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                    o.worldPos = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex);
                    o.screenPos = ComputeScreenPos(o.vertex);
                    UNITY_TRANSFER_FOG(o,o.vertex);
                    return o;
                }
//...
                float2 boxIntersection(in float3 ro, in float3 rd, in float3 rad)
                {
                    float3 m = 1.0 / rd;
                    float3 n = m * ro;
                    float3 k = abs(m) * rad;
                    float3 t1 = -n - k;
                    float3 t2 = -n + k;

                    float tN = max(max(t1.x, t1.y), t1.z);
                    float tF = min(min(t2.x, t2.y), t2.z);

                    if (tN > tF || tF < 0.0) return float2(-1.0, -1.0); // no intersection

                    return float2(tN, tF);
                }

                //p in object space
                float SampleValue(float3 p) {
                    float totalValue = 0.0;
                    float denom = 0.0;

                    for (int i = 0; i < 34; ++i) {   // _DataSize
                        float4 sd = _SensorData[i];
                        float dist = length(p - sd.xyz);

                        totalValue += sd.w / (dist * dist);
                        denom += 1.0 / (dist * dist);
                    }

                    if (denom == 0.0) {
                        return 0.0;
                    }

                    return totalValue / denom;
                }

                float4 transferFunction(float value) {
                    float tv = (value - _DataScale.x) / (_DataScale.y - _DataScale.x);   // _DataScale.x, _DataScale.y

                    float4 col = tex2D(_TransferTexture, float2(0.5, tv));
                    col.w *= _Strength;     // _Strength
                    return float4(col.xyz * col.w, col.w);
                }

                float4 rayMarch(float3 ro, float3 rd, float dp) {
                    float3 ro1 = mul(unity_WorldToObject, float4(ro, 1.0));
                    float3 rd1 = mul(unity_WorldToObject, rd);

                    float2 t = boxIntersection(ro1, rd1, float3(1, 1, 1) * 0.5);
                    t.x = length(mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, float4(ro1 + rd1 * max(t.x, 0.0), 1.0)) - ro);
                    t.y = length(mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, float4(ro1 + rd1 * t.y, 1.0)) - ro);
                    t.y = min(t.y, dp);

                    float4 acc = float4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

                    float totalDelta = (t.y - t.x);
                    float delta = totalDelta / float(_RM_Samples - 1.0);

                    float3 p = ro + t.x * rd;

                    for (int i = 0; i < 34; ++i) {   // _RM_Samples
                        float v = SampleValue(p);

                        float4 tf = transferFunction(v);

                    float tr = exp(-tf.w * delta);

                    acc.xyz += tf.xyz * acc.w * delta;
                    acc.w *= tr;

                    p += delta * rd;
                    }

                    return float4(acc.xyz, (1.0 - acc.w) * step(t.x, t.y));
                }

            fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                float2 tc = i.screenPos.xy / i.screenPos.w;
                float depth = UNITY_SAMPLE_DEPTH(tex2D(_CameraDepthTexture, tc));
                float eD = LinearEyeDepth(depth);

                float3 ro = _WorldSpaceCameraPos;
                float3 rd = normalize(i.worldPos - ro);

                float4 col = rayMarch(ro, rd, eD);
                //if (col.w < 1) col = float4(1, 0, 0, 1); 
                //else col = float4(0, 1, 0, 1);
                if (wingCullPlaneValue(i.worldPos.xyz) == 0 || cullPlaneValue(i.worldPos.xyz) == 0) {
                    discard;
                }

                UNITY_APPLY_FOG(i.fogCoord, col);
                return col;
            }
```

Since this works fine in Editor, I don't think there is any error in `boxIntersection` or `rayMarching` functions. I wonder if there is anything special in WebGl that it processes the pixels differently, and I has to tweak some codes accordingly. I am new to WebGL and Shader, and would appreciate any help or advice, thanks in advance.

Comment: You may have to put your shader in the list of "Always Included Shaders" inside the player settings. Otherwise, it will not be included in the build unless some asset used in a scene references it. Also, make sure that your quality settings support camera depth texture.

Comment: I have a similar problem. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

that's because of the step function.
Approximate it with your own sigmoid function (might be expensive)

```
float emulated_step(float a, float x){
    return 1.0/(1+pow(1000, -(x-a)*8192));
}
```